# What is a decently-powerful, thematically-infernal spell to replace Protection from Good?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, house-rules

I'm making a Bloodrager(infernal)/Sorcerer(draconic). A devil planted a seed of darkness in the boy's soul and as an adult he has to learn to fight and control it. House rules allow two bloodlines.

The problem is the spell *protection from good*. He's a neutral good character and has no need for this spell, so I want to swap it for something he can use.

What would be a decently powerful spell that will fit the theme of devil blood and won't unbalance the game?

Comment: He is asking for a non-underpowered, infernally themed, first level sorcerer bloodline spell. That's neither broad or opinion-based.

Answer (score 7):

Don't replace it. You have a shard of an infernal "prince" (title inflation is so... common in hell these days) in you, and it should provide power as it wants.

Evil is known for it's subtle seduction as well as its more overt corruption and destruction. "Hey, if you fight these guys," a voice from your soul whispers, "they won't hit you as often. And we all know that this morality stuff is relative. What have they done for you recently that makes them Good in *your* eyes?"

Not every spell has to be amazing, and if you're playing at an absurd power level, you have multiple bloodlines *so that* you can ignore these less good options. In pathfinder, the protections are alignment based, but the spell still offers you some universal protections against enchantment. As a level 1 spell gained at 7th level, this option was *never* intended to be amazing, merely flavourful. Protection from good is that flavour.

Of *course*, if you felt like arguing your case in front of your parents' infernal patron, I'm *sure* he'd be willing to ... make a deal. It was *just business,* after all. That deal, however, should directly benefit the devil *more* than it benefits you, and should be a level 1 abjuration spell. This is another area where trying to argue against yourself is problematic. It's *quite hard* to be a successful tempter to yourself without being unduly generous.

Comment: and on another topic, what does protection from good do in terms of enchantment? does it protect against all enchantment?

Comment: Step 1. Read the spell. Step 2, after having done research, ask a new question.

Answer (score 2):

How about [Infernal Healing](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/i/infernal-healing), a first level spell that gives fast healing 1 for a minute and uses devil blood as a component? It's really the most "infernal" first level spell. However, the protection spells are pretty handy, you could just swap for protection from chaos (also opposed to devils) and still get a lot of use from it.